# Add custom method to Spring RepositoryRestResource

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-rest

Is it possible to add custom methods to a Spring `@RepositoryRestResource` and have them exposed as HTTP endpoints, as the example below tries (and fails) to do?  Or must I put custom methods in a separate `@Controller`?

```java
@RepositoryRestResource(path="person")
public interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person,Long> {

    // This works, as it's an integral part of what RepositoryRestResource does:
    // curl localhost:8080/person/search/findByNameStartsWith?prefix=MA
    Iterable<Person> findByNameStartsWith(@Param("prefix") String prefix);

    // This doesn't work:
    // curl -X POST -v localhost:8080/person/3/sendWelcomeLetter
    @RequestMapping(path = "/{id}/sendWelcomeLetter", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    default String sendWelcomeLetter(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
        return "This is a custom method that would generate and send a letter.";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

sendWelcomeLetter is not ReST. ST in ReST mean "state-transfer", your call is dynamic without state transfer.

A minimal solution might be to add a new nullable column "sent_welcome_newsletter".

- `null` means the welcome-newsletter is not sent yet.
- `false` means the welcome newsletter can not be delivered (inbox full or invalid email).
- `true` means the welcome newsletter has been sent successfully in the past.

But: Beware of the [legal right](https://certified-senders.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/CSA_Admission_Criteria.pdf) to not be blocked by DNSBL. Without respecting this criterias your company will become huge legal problems what might lead in your unemployment!!!!

Comment: I'm exploring how to match my architecture to the Spring functionality, and your suggestion is one of the options I'm looking at, along with creating Command entities to invoke processing while staying within the REST paradigm, and a more object-oriented API with method invocation.  I don't feel a need to be strictly RESTful, I'm more concerned the best way to implement my functionality within Spring.

My entities are not actually people, nor am I intending to spam anyone!  :)    I chose that entity and action as examples as I thought they'd be more familiar terms than my actual data model.

Comment: The public question you have chosen is different from the actual problem due to protect the product and/or company. As you already noticed, this is "one of the options" what require to have contributions to the model.

Answer (score 0):

please go thru this.
https://dzone.com/articles/add-custom-functionality-to-a-spring-data-reposito

U can use  @RestResource inside the class as below

```
  @RepositoryRestResource(path = "people")
  interface PersonRepository extends CrudRepository<Person, Long> {

    @RestResource(path = "names")
    List<Person> findByName(String name);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do `@RequestMapping` in the repository interface to map the endpoint with the default method as you have shown.
According to the documentation

> This repository is an interface that lets you perform various operations involving Person objects. It gets these operations by extending the PagingAndSortingRepository interface that is defined in Spring Data Commons.

> At runtime, Spring Data REST automatically creates an implementation of this interface. Then it uses the @RepositoryRestResource annotation to direct Spring MVC to create RESTful endpoints at /people.

To achieve what you want to do you have to create the endpoint in new `@RestController` and using service you should use `PersonRepository` to get the person and then perform your operation.